# Как изменить css элемента исходя из текста?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, css3, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<body>
<h1 align="center">HTML Code Example</h1>
 <div>
  <h4 class="title">Example Title<h4>
  <span>Blah blah blah<span>
  <span class="general-buttons" onclick="deletePost();">(Delete)<span>
  <span align="right" class="general-buttons" onclick="window.history.back();">[Back]</span>
 </div>
</body>
```

Можно ли изменить стиль кнопки Delete не затрагивая другие элементы с помощью текста внутри элемента? Может это возможно с помощью jQuery или JS(Ванильного)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стиль конкретной кнопки можно с помощью jQuery приведённой ниже строкой:

```js
$("span:contains('(Delete)')").css('background-color', '#fdd60391');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1 align="center">HTML Code Example</h1>
 <div>
  <h4 class="title">Example Title<h4>
  <span>Blah blah blah<span>
  <span class="general-buttons" onclick="deletePost();">(Delete)<span>
  <span align="right" class="general-buttons" onclick="window.history.back();">[Back]</span>
 </div>
</body>
```